# Get env value to model laravel?

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I have problem with date format in laravel model for different operating system (windows & linux) SQL Server

How to get the value from env to model, I create variable in .env for set condition in model when value variable environment 1 = windows and 2 = linux

// 1 FOR WINDOWS
// 2 FOR LINUX SERVER 
ENVIRONMENT=1

Any solution / advice for this case?

Comment: Hello, I don't have any advice, but, in order to fetch an variable from .env use this: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables in your .env files are parsed as strings, so some reserved values have been created to allow you to return a wider range of types from the env() function.

make sure you already execute this command to clear your config after you added that variable to your config.

```
php artisan config:clear
```

**Retrieving Environment Configuration**

```
<?php
   $environment =  env("environment", 1)
?>
```

The second value passed to the env function is the "default value". This value will be used if no environment variable exists for the given key.

see docs here [env](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration)

Comment: Okay @Qonvex620

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel function env() returns values from `.env` file.
So if you have `ENVIROMENT = 1` in your `.env`, using `env('ENVIRONMENT')`, you will get that value.